# C++: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c++

I'm getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "isValidFormat(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >)", referenced from:
      _main in main-970001.o
  "readFile(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-970001.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when trying to build my code.

isValidFormat is

```
bool isValidFormat(vector<string> fileContent);
```

and readFile is

```
vector<string> readFile(ifstream& file);
```

These functions don't have anything in them yet as I'm testing other stuff first.
I'm using an M1 MacBook Air.

Comment: Do these functions have an implementation or just a declaration? If they're just a declaration, are you still trying to call them?

Comment: _These functions don't have anything in them yet_...that raises some concerns.  Minimally, including an implementation like `bool isValidFormat(vector<string> fileContent) { return bool(); }` (or throwing a not-implemented exception) is necessary to get it to link.  The declaration alone `bool isValidFormat(vector<string> fileContent);` with no function body is not enough and will give the _Undefined symbols_ error.